# is there a good design pattern for this classes relation in Python?

Tags: python, class, design-patterns

So imagine I have a class A, and class B can take class A as its member and use class A's functionality to do the job, like this

```
 class B:
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.A = A

    def do_something(self):
        # some other jobs ....
        self.A.do_the_job()
```

This is a straightforward design. However, in my case, class A can be accessed and modified outside of B as well, then this design is a little strange because although A is a member class of B, actually A could be changing its status outside of B. Therefore I change it to this design

```
 class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_something(self, A):
        # some other jobs ....
        A.do_the_job()
```

It is definitely perfectly fine, the only ugly thing is, right now everytime when I call `B.do_something`, I need to pass class A as its argument. Actually class B has several other functions that will use class A as well.

I wonder if there is any better design pattern to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: In your second example, can't `A` still be modified before calling `B.do_something(A)`? If `do_the_job()` is a documented function of `A` then you should be able to count on that. If you can't, what *can* you trust?

Comment: What is your issue with the fact that the instance of `A` can change outside the class? If you want to avoide to pass `a` (instance of `A`) as a parameter use the upper design and clearly document this bahavior in the docstring of the function.

Comment: Your first design isn't strange at all. Consider `file = open('test'); reader = csv.reader(file)` same relationship. In Python, this is always possible.

Comment: If you don't want `self.A` to be modified out of the class, don't take `A` as a parameter. Create the `A` instance in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Changing the class outsinde of `B` will also changing the class stored in `B` as both operations will work on the same instance of `A`. But you are most probably aware of that. If you don't want this behavior you could generate the instance of `A` in the `__init__` of `B` so that it is exclusive to `B`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s pretty simple:

```
class A:
    def do(self):
        print(“Hello from A”)
class B:
    def run(self):
        A().do()
        print(“Now in B”)
```

So yes, you can just access one class in another in this way. Remember that if your classes are in different files you must use the line like that:

```
from mymodule import A
```

and it will work as well